# Big-O and division by constant

Tags: algorithm, constants, big-o

I think this is a simple question, but if I have something like O(n²/2), should I just get rid of the /2 and conclude that O(n²)?

Comment: Yes, dividing/multiplying by a constant does not change the big-O.

Comment: yes, constants factors don't matter

Comment: yes .In big -o we are interested in rate of growth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Yeah`, you should get rid of all the constant terms involved in the O-notation.

The big O notation describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity, usually in terms of simpler functions.

> It is an upper bound,which can be re-framed even after removing the
>   constants from inside the O-notation.

O(g(x)) should be reduced to the simplest function in terms of the `n`...